# $.parseJson with html encoded string

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I receive an html encoded string from server code and I want to convert it to JSON using `$.parseJSON` but it throws the exception. This is the string returned by asp.net's JavaScript serializer:

```
{"Property":"Name","Template":"\u003cinput data-val=\"true\" data-val-number=\"The field ID must be a number.\"....
```

String is correct as returned by JS serializer but when I call

```
var data = '<%=serializer.Serialize(Model))%>';
data = $.parseJson(data);
// I also tried $.parseJSON(unescape(data)) but with no luck
```

The situation is that I can't prevent html encoding of string on server side. How can I parse this string to JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JSON is basically just literal JS code for defining a variable's contents, you could just skip the whole json parseing step with:

```
var data = <%= serializer.Serialize(Model)) %>; // note: no quotes
alert(data.Property);
```

Comment: the removal of the quotes is key.

Comment: i tried it without quotes but it complains that data.0 is null or not an object

Comment: sorry i was still trying to $.parseJson. it is perfectly working now. thanks a lot